# PowerApps : Custom Connector with MS Graph : How can I use Application permissions in my custom connector?

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, powerapps, power-automate-custom-connector

I am having trouble creating a PowerApps Custom Connector which allows me to access Microsoft Graph using APPLICATION permissions.

I have created my Azure AD App Registration, with three API permissions:

- Delegated: User.Read
- Application: User.Read.All
- Application: Directory.Read.All

I have confirmed the Redirect URI is correctly set for Power Apps (https://global.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect) and I have generated a Client Secret.

I have then created TWO different Power Apps custom connectors, and both of them give me exactly the same results.

1. **Connector A:** Auth Type: OAuth2.0

   - Identity Provider: Generic OAuth 2
   - Client ID & Client Secret (as expected)
   - Auth URL: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{Tenant](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BTenant) ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
   - Token URL: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{Tenant](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BTenant) ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token
   - Scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
2. **Connector B:** Auth Type: OAuth 2.0

   - Identify Provider: Azure Active Directory
   - Client ID & Client Secret (as expected)
   - Login URL: https://login.windows.net
   - Tenant ID: common (this is the default)
   - Resource URL: https://graph.microsoft.com
   - Scope: {blank} (this is the default)

I then setup (in both connectors) the same two actions:

- /v1.0/me
- /v1.0/users

In BOTH connectors the first action (/me) works .. and returns the details of the logged in user.
The second connector (/users) returns "Access Denied - Insufficient Privileges".

This is telling me it is using the Delegated permissions (which allows it to retrieve /me) and not the Application permissions (which is why it can't list all of the user accounts).

So .. is there any setting in Power Apps which allows me to specify that this connector should use Application requests rather than delegated?

Thank you!

Comment: You are using the User Context Flow, so please add delegated permissions Users.Read.All and it will work. If you want to use Application permissions you need to use Application Context Flow and get the token.

Comment: How do I configure Power Apps to use the Application Context Flow ?
Is this something I need to specify in the custom connector, or in the AAD App Registration?

Comment: You are using Auth Code Flow where you hit /authorize endpoint and get the code and use it to hit the /token endpoint and login with your account and get the user context token. Here you would directly hit token endpoint by providing few parameters. See [Client Credential Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

Comment: What I specifically need to know - is this possible in the Power Apps platform - in a Custom Connector.

I have this fully working in PostMan using Application context flow requests - I just can't work out how to do this in PowerApps

Comment: It's not supported to use client credentials flow in custom connector currently. Vote the User Voice pots [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/42103957-add-custom-connector-authentication-support-for-oa) and [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Add-support-for-OAuth2-Client-Credentials-auth-flow-in-Custom/idi-p/427348) if you need this feature.